# 16.04 kernel Update breaks power saving - how to fix?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, power-management, battery, powertop

I used to have 7-9 hours of battery life on my system running 16.04LTS.  But, recently, I noticed battery life halving to around 4.5 hours. It seems this has been going on since around May '18.

[image]

Installing and booting kernel `4.14.33` gives me back old battery life

[image]

The only problem is that installing kernel `4.14.33` gives some errors relating to Virtualbox and Nvidia drivers.

So, how can I fix this problem with the current 16.04LTS kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the culprit.

A kernel update seems to have disrupted the NVIDIA proprietary driver setup.

[image]

Original driver was 384.130.
Switching to X.Org, rebooting and then switching back to 384.130 seemed enough to put the driver back into working order.

In the meantime I updated to version 390 using

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt update
```

and then choosing the 390 driver in the additional drivers tab.
(It says open source, but the repository is for proprietary drivers only, as far as I see - so this must be a mistake.)

Then used nvidia-xconfig to use only onboard Intel and rebooted.

my notebook now is back to normal energy consumption:

[image]